# I am getting these errors while running services in my Angular 4 app

Tags: angular

```
log
close 
socket/sock.onclose
../../../../sockjs-client/lib/event/eventtarget.js/EventTarget.prototype.dispatchEvent 
../../../../sockjs-client/lib/main.js/</SockJS.prototype._close/<  in  'http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js'

../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask 
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</Zone.prototype.runTask 
../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js/</</ZoneTask.invokeTask
```

ZoneTask/this.invoke
timer                               'http://localhost:4200/polyfills.bundle.js'

Comment: Please provide more of your code, what you've posted so far will make it difficult for anyone to help you.

Comment: fixed typo and capitalizations